# javascriptの値をphpに渡す

Tags: javascript, php

javascriptの値を同フォルダ内の別phpファイルに値を渡したいのですがどうすればいいでしょうか？

Comment: getでquery stringにくっつけてやるか、formつかってpostしてやれば良いかと。

Comment: この質問は解決されましたでしょうか？もし解決に至らず、他の補足情報などあれば質問文に追記してください。また、質問者様の過去の質問を拝見しましたが、一度も承認されていないように見受けられます。解決した場合は承認を行い後から見た人がどの回答で解決したかわかるようにして下さい。

Answer (score 1):

サーバにあるPHPファイルに値を送信するしかないです。
単純にJavaScriptでPHPファイルへのパラメータ付きURLを作成し、そのURLをブラウザで開くか、
遷移せずJavaScriptから非同期に送信する方法があります。

```
//送りたいデータ例
var values = {
  'val1':'test value one',
  'val2':'test value two',
  'val3':'test value three'
};
//対象のPHPパス
var phpUrl = './target.php';

//送信パラメータ作成
var work = [];
for(key in values){ work.push(key+"="+values[key]); }
var requests = work.join("&");

//何も考えずに遷移するなら
location.href = phpUrl + '?' + requests;

//非同期に送信するなら
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', phpUrl, false);
xhr.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
xhr.send(requests);
xhr.abort();
```